# How to randomly fill X of rows in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to randomly fill the rows of a dataframe by setting a number? For example:

Given a pandas dataframe with 10 elements:

```
col1
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

How to fill randomly with `1` and the rest with `0` in the rows of another column. For example, I would like to fill four rows with `1` and the rest six `0`:

```
col1 col2
a     1
b     0
c     1
d     1
e     0
f     1
g     0
h     0
i     0
j     0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick. For each row, set the col2 to a random int between 0 and 1

```
df["col2"] = df.apply(lambda x: randint(0,1), axis=1)
```

If you need n random values to exist and the rest to be set, you can try this:

```
n = 4
df["col2"] = 0
df_to_update = df.sample(n)
df_to_update = 1
df.update(df_to_update)
```

Comment: Here in what part are you controlling the number of 0s and 1s? In this case I would like to have four 0 and six 1. Is there any way to approach this with dummies or fillna?

Comment: @tumbleweed answering in the edit of this post

Answer (score 1):

Credit goes to @bguest for the *how* behind all of this, but I wanted a single-line answer to this question and hacked the following:

```
df['col2']      = pd.np.where(df.merge(df.sample(4).assign(col2 = 1), on = 'col1', how = 'left')['col2'].notnull(), 1, 0)
```